# Laravel "make" relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in Laravel version 10 attempting to create relationship instances without persisting them to the database until a `save()` is called.

I have something like the following.

```php
$detail = OrderDetail::make([
    'example' => 'example',
]);

$detail->imprints()->make(['imprintID' => 1]);

// ... Other code is executed

$detail->save(); // Should persist the detail and the imprint
```

I've tried a few different things. The stipulation is that I'd like the OrderDetail model to be aware of the imprints since the OrderDetail will be passed around to a couple of different classes before it's ultimately persisted in the database.

Is there a way to accomplish this without creating my own relationship structures?

The imprints method is simply

```php
class OrderDetail extends Model{

    public function imprints(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderDetailImprint::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is there is no 'id' for the OrderDetail yet so the child has nothing to save for that key ... this `make` call isn't adding this child to a collection on the parent or anything like that, so the `save` call on the parent isn't doing anything for the child ... you could look into the `push` method but you would have to add this child to a collection (returned by the dynamic property) to have it save the parent and all related models

Answer (score 0):

As @lagbox was saying, and also through my own research it doesn't seem like there's an elegant way to push the non-persisted related models onto the parent.

So in my haste, I've rolled up my own solution on my BaseModel like so.

```php
abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{

    /**
     * Stores models that are related to this model but aren't yet
     * persisted to the databse
     * @var array
     */
    private $relatedMakeModels = [];

    /**
     * Store related models to be saved along with the model.
     * @param Model $model The related model to be saved
     * @param string $relationFunction The function name to call.
     */
    public function makeRelatedModel(Model $model, string $relationFunction): Model
    {
        $this->relatedMakeModels[] = [
            'model' => $model,
            'relation_function' => $relationFunction,
        ];
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Override.
     * Save the model to the database.
     * @param array $options
     * @return bool
     */
    public function save(array $options = []): bool
    {
        $result = parent::save($options);

        foreach ($this->relatedMakeModels as $model) {
            $this->{$model['relation_function']}()->save($model['model']);
        }

        $this->relatedMakeModels = [];

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I'll not accept this answer as I still believe there SHOULD be a way to do this in Laravel. Seems like an oversight.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#the-push-method  that is the built in way

Comment: Seems like that's designed for relationships that already have an ID as well. Looking through the Relationship classes that's just how they are designed, with `foreignKey` and 'localKey' properties to do the work.